# running node.js command from browser

Tags: node.js, browser

I've got node.js running on my server and it seems to be working.  I'm able to run a .js script from the command line.

This is one basic script I've been testing:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello World');
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Once I run the script as follows from the command line:

```
node test.js
```

I am able to go to localhost:8080 and see the response.

So that is great.  But I need to be able to do this from the browser.  My understanding based on research and examples is that I have to include this file within the web page:

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

From what I've found in my research, this doesn't refer to an actual file location but if node.js is installed it will get the proper library.  But all I get is a 404 file not found error.  There are various socket.io.js files on the server that got dropped there during the node.js installation, but none seem to have the required functions for running the script.

From PHP I can run this .js file from the command line.  Some I'm not concerned that the file can't be run.  But I want to be able to listen for changes on the client side, so I'd still need to have a separate browser-based script to listen for these posts.

This doesn't seem like it should be that difficult to determine, but I've been going through the web for the past two days and haven't had any luck.  Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually using socket.io? Do you need to or would ajax suffice?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.  That's a url on your server.  If you say just `socket.io/socket.io.js`, that's a web page on the socket.io domain (see here: [socket.io/socket.io.js](http://socket.io/socket.io.js)) which doesn't exist, so you're getting a 404.

Comment: I get the same error either way.  Specifically from firebug I get NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js"

Comment: @user3521590 It sounds like you haven't actually set up the server side of `socket.io`.  Follow the instructions that @cybersam linked to in his answer.

Comment: socket.io was one of the first things I installed following installation of node.js, running the command npm install socket.io

Comment: @user3521590 Yes, but installing it isn't enough.  You have to require it in your server-side script and use it.